# Merging two dataframes with a common and uncommon keys in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframes that I would like to merge. Merge df2 to df1.

```
df1  = {'ID1': ['A12', 'A13', 'A14','A15'], 'ArrivalDateTime': ["2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-26","2022-01-20"]} 
df2  = {'ID': ['A12', 'A12', '003','A15','A15'], 'ArrivalDateCap': ["2021-09-17", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-20","2022-01-17","2022-01-19"]}  
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)  
df1["ArrivalDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["ArrivalDateTime"],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2["ArrivalDateCap"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["ArrivalDateCap"],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

The common columns are ID1 in df1 and ID in df2. In addition, if they match(left join df1 and df2), I need to look for ArrivalDateCap less than but  closest to the value in ArrivalDateTime for that record. That's the record from df2 that should  be  picked  if more than one  matching records exist. Sample output should be  as below:

```
output_df  = {'ID': ['A12', 'A13', 'A14','A15'], 'ArrivalDateTime': ["2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-26","2022-01-20"],'ID1':['A12','A13','A14','A15'],'ArrivalDateCap':['2021-09-17',np.NaN,np.NaN,'2022-01-19']}  
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_df)
```

Can I use pandas.merge_asof for this? If so, how can I define  the ID1 and ID as well as ArrivalDateTime and ArrivalDateCap for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) first:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2.sort_values('ArrivalDateCap'), 
                   left_by='ID1', 
                   right_by='ID', 
                   left_on='ArrivalDateTime', 
                   right_on='ArrivalDateCap')
print (df)
   ID1 ArrivalDateTime   ID ArrivalDateCap
0  A12      2021-09-20  A12     2021-09-17
1  A13      2021-09-21  NaN            NaT
2  A14      2021-09-26  NaN            NaT
3  A15      2022-01-20  A15     2022-01-19
```

And then for replace missing values use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(df['ID1'])
print (df)
   ID1 ArrivalDateTime   ID ArrivalDateCap
0  A12      2021-09-20  A12     2021-09-17
1  A13      2021-09-21  A13            NaT
2  A14      2021-09-26  A14            NaT
3  A15      2022-01-20  A15     2022-01-19
```

Comment: Sure done  it. Was just thinking out loud , what of the two dates are one day apart. A day before and  a day after. How will the  merge happen/likely to happen?

Comment: @Hummer - I think then need change `direction='backward'` (default value, so should be omit like in my answer) to `direction='nearest'` if need match nearest match.